# Typescript class method which takes the instance type of the caller

Tags: typescript, class

Suppose i have a class constructor which takes an object containing some of its class properties, and a method to assign these properties in the same way.

```
class MainClass {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  constructor(props: Partial<MainClass> = {}){
    this.a = props.a ?? 'None';
    this.b = props.b ?? 1;
  }
  public assign(props: Partial<MainClass> = {}){
     Object.keys(props).forEach(key => {
        this[key] = props[key]
    })
  }
}
```

If I wanted to extend the class like so

```
class SubClass extends MainClass {
   c: boolean;
   constructor(props: Partial<SubClass> = {}){
      super(props)
      this.c = props.c ?? true;
   }
}
```

`SubClass`'s method `assign` still wants a `Partial<MainClass>` type.

How do I define the type of `props` in the method to be assigned according to the calling instance?

Side-note: any feedback on the code itself and what would be considered bad practices are welcome.

Comment: Uh, are you writing `Parital` when you mean `Partial`?  Does your TS compiler understand that?

Comment: I wrote this code right in the question input, not copied from my text editor. beware: typos ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance members like `assign()` you can use a [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) instead of `MainClass`.  It is similar to a generic type parameter which gets narrowed to the specific type of the object on which the member is accessed:

```
  public assign(props: Partial<this> = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, props); // shorter impl
  }
```

Inside the *implementation* of your `MainClass` or even `SubClass` classes, the exact type of `this` won't be known.  But when you *use* an instance of these classes, the type will be narrowed to the type of the instance:

```
const mainClass = new MainClass();
mainClass.assign({ c: false }); // compiler error as usual
// --------------> ~~~~~~~~
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 
// 'c' does not exist in type 'Partial<MainClass>

const subClass = new SubClass();
subClass.assign({ c: false }); // okay
console.log(JSON.stringify(subClass)); // {"a":"None","b":1,"c":false}
```

Note how `subClass.assign()` expects a `Partial<SubClass>` while `mainClass.assign()` expects a `Partial<MainClass>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyYEsB2BhcVoG8CwAoa0YAXNBAC4BOyA5gNx4EBGJSArgLaMCmF9+0wAPZJyFVsDKCKACgAOFQbIgkACmApkEYEAB54yNJAgA+aAF4sAXwCUWBgWhkAFgggA6MOejzF7zwH5-aAByADlhLmC+B0cXd0YvHyU3BMDoAEZo6Et7WVZGEARgQigEaiQ5BSVVdU1tHWdXUwtMGzt+AgB5RgArLgkPUvLpRogAGm8qiGssnNw5vFAjaABlfMMMLgAPMi4kABMYfVR0GBx+YBJGQUEQLjAkLKERSnFJGSTlaDUNLV01xgbExeVq2c4xCCsWQ8Sq+az2AijNzFCyfZHQNKvLizPALXDPcjQdiIE7LCxILgAdzgJKB0hmeGJBlOgwgZQqmAEJAAZtoIFxsjNoAB6YUCQTsWQIO4UaA8BSyyDQViQ7R4UXQAC02p1ut1pgAfkbjUb1WLun0JNBCrsKNoiWAAJ7QYQgZ0QaHABDc50AayQgkpSEmih4mi440IB2gZpCwGC0H2ggj0ADZDlW1c6eQjkd0JCPzqumOQOMeEWwkJkMBpy8FOpALpDNw1aBrPZ0k5l2gvJA-MFtBFYsEvqdFZEty4bhAgmo0gAUitOqE3KIaN7HdJW6drEKNZgAERgA9EA-hCkHsYHxgn9JX4An3v8vFAA)